# How to dynamically change the Formula's column when I update an Reference Cell with the my Column Name in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets-formula

How to automatically update the Formula's Column value when you change the Value in Reference row?

Example:
First Column (A) has Static DATA
I am multiplying Column (A) DATA with Column-B/ Column-C/ Column-D/ Column-E/ Column-F

Column-G has my Formula:

```
=$A2*B2
```

I have now created a Reference cell at K2

For Eg:
When I update the K2 cell with the letter **D**
I want the formula at that Column-G to automatically update as

```
= $A2*D2
```

Reference Sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Qlzb8jdhd8Vpcs3LNv3_MlKF1SfU2rOaAtdWBdYRkxI/edit?usp=sharing

I am not able to figure out how to automatically update the formula based on a reference cell value as I change. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
=$A2*indirect($K$1&row())
```

see [indirect](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377) and [row](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093316)

Comment: Thanks. This works great.